# Indefnite Integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Question : If I write Integrate[- Xi[2]' [t] + 2 **Xi[1]]^(1,0) [x,t]**== 0, x]  , the bold part is the partial differential of Xi[1] with respect x.
                I get an answer that has an integral sign.  And that is not what I want as output.

I know how to solve it manually, but how do I integrate and make Xi the subject of the formula?

Comment: (1) I don't think `Integrate` will operate on an equation. (2) Your code contains syntax errors.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Perhaps you should use `DSolve`: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html

Comment: mattiav27 DSolve returns an empty set in my case. DSolve does not work in this case. Something else to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably created your integrand by using [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D):

```
integrand = -Xi[2]'[t] + 2 D[Xi[1][x, t], x];
```

The output looks like the integrand in your expression:

[image]

The [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm) looks quite different:

```
integrand //InputForm
```

> -Derivative[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfGVn.png)[Xi[2]][t] + 2*Derivative[1, 0][Xi[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfGVn.png)][x, t]

Now, taking into account @MichaelE2's comment that Integrate doesn't work with equations, you should use:

```
Integrate[integrand, x] //TeXForm
```

> $2 \operatorname{Xi}(1)(x,t)-x \operatorname{Xi}(2)'(t)$

where I use [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) as it produces a reasonable facsimile of the output you see in Mathematica.

Comment: I did not get the output you got from Integrate[integrand, x] //TeXForm

Comment: The end goal is to solve for Xi(1)(x,t) from the output==0. Simply put to make Xi(1) the subject of the formula from the output==0.